# pandas truncate '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'Timestamp'

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

I've got following code:

```
import pandas as pd

t_start = pd.to_datetime('2022-02-14T06:32:54.332000')
t_end = pd.to_datetime('2022-02-14T06:35:24.880000')

lower = df.truncate(after=t_start).shape[0]-1
upper = df.truncate(after=t_end).shape[0]+1
# resample and return subset between start and end
selection = df.iloc[lower:upper, :]
selection_resampled = selection.resample(str(10) + 'ms').ffill()
```

The goal is to resample/upsample the selection range of a time series data frame. But for what reason ever, I get the message

> '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'Timestamp'

(that happens for the calculation of lower and upper)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'d':pd.date_range('2022-02-14T06:20:54.332000', '2022-02-14T06:50:54.332000', periods = 10)})
t_start = pd.to_datetime('2022-02-14T06:32:54.332000')
t_end = pd.to_datetime('2022-02-14T06:35:24.880000')
df[(df['d']<t_end)&(df['d']>t_start)]
```

output:

[image]

Then you can do the other stuffs.